# Save object to file. "Delete object", but find it in a statistic- and history search. UPDATED

Tags: java, object, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I am working on a insurance-schoolproject where I should be able to create a new client, add insurances (house, car, boat, etc) and save to file. I am using

```
public void skrivTilFil(HashMap hm)  {
    if ( hm != null ) {
        try (ObjectOutputStream utStream = 
                new ObjectOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(filename))) {
            utStream.writeObject (hm);
```

The thing is that I should be able to delete objects (a house-, a car-insurance, the client itself, etc) BUT I must have a history- and statisticsearch where both the objects and deleted objects show.

I have thought about saving to two different files, and delete from just one file. Meaning I have one file where I delete and an other file for the history- and statisticsearch. But I am definitely not allowes to double-save.  So I understand it so I only can have one file therefore cannot delete the objects.

I have also thought about having a boolean value where "`false`" = `show`, and "`true`" = `deleted`. Then show only "`show-objects`" and not "`deleted`" when necessary, and both "`false`" and "`true`" when searching history and statistics.

So I have made this method:

```
public void eraseCustomer( int insurancenr )
{
    Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Person>> iterator = vindu.register.personTM.entrySet().iterator() ;
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        Map.Entry<Integer, Person> insuranceNrEntry = iterator.next();
        if( insurancenr == insuranceNrEntry.getKey())
        {
            Vindu.setUtskriftsomraadet("Found person " +     insuranceNrEntry.getValue() );

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "arrived at eraseCustomer");
```

}

Running this code shows that I get a value, like "Person@2936643".
What I need is to get the name of the person/object (String lastname) and to set that personboolean to true. 
I have a insurancenrkey to find this person. 
So 1:
Is it possible to update that personobject with boolean = true an easy way, or do I have to make a new object and then replace it with the object I found? I just need to change the booleanvalue, not the name, birthday, etc.
2:
How do I get the name of the object and not Person@2936643?

The thing is that this is way over my knowledge... Do you have any tips or suggestions on how I can do this, that would be very much appreciated!

(I'm norwegian so please excuse me for the bad english)

Comment: You might consider using a relational database as an alternative, mapping the data to java objects when necessary,

Comment: There are several approaches you can take. Since you're already saving history to a file you only need to maintain the current state as objects.  Then when you need to recall history, you can either read from the file, or before you delete something save a "snapshot" object into a data structure maintaining the history.

A database would be ideal, but you could mimic a database structure via Java objects depending on the requirements of this assignment.  One way to maintain history is with a begin and end timestamp where you expire records. Another way is with a current record indicator.

Comment: You're idea about having a boolean would be like a current record indicator or a delete flag.  I see nothing wrong with that approach.

Comment: I'm gonna talk with my two other group members about your inputs and come back to this. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: getLastName() made it easy. Working on how to put insuranceStatus() = false in the abstract Insurance-class from Person-class